# changing a python script while it is running

Tags: python

Assume I have some python script - script.py, and I run it using

```
python script.py &
```

and now it runs for a long time and write some results to a file. Is it ok (i.e., it won't ruin the current run) to change script.py while it is running? can it affect the current run? I'm using Ubuntu if it matters.
Thanks

Comment: No, changes you make to the script while it's being run won't be seen in the interpreter that's already loaded the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the script, because when you start it, it's compiled to bytecode which is being executed.